# Converting if else constraints into linear ones

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I have the following two constraints:

$$
x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \qquad \mbox{if } x_1 \leq x_3 \\
x_1 > x_2 > x_3 \qquad \mbox{otherwise}
$$

Is there a way to get rid of the two conditions and end up with linear constraint(s) only?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in what kind of problem are you using that constraint? what are you representing, if I may ask?

Comment: Oh, the x's are essentially scaling design variables applied in the chordwise direction of a wing (so to achieve nonlinear taper).  The above constraints are meant to force a scaling design variable to always stay between the bounds of the other two that sandwich it.  I needed that in an attempt to eliminate "zigzags" in the graph of scale vs span.  By the way, I really like how you convert my problem to a min/max one, but if I understand correctly I'd need to introduce "slack" variables which unfortunately is not ideal for me.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, perhaps not the most efficient, can be as follows: your constraint can be rewritten as:

$$ \min(x_1, x_3) \leq x_2 \leq \max(x_1,x_3) $$

therefore, you can introduce two positive variables $t$ and $k$ such that:

$$ t \leq x_1 \\
t \leq x_3 \\
k \geq x_1\\
k \geq x_3 $$

Putting $t$ and $k$ in the objective function with suitable coefficients, you can end up with $t = \min(x_1,x_3)$ and $k = \max(x_1,x_3)$.
So, your constraint becomes:
$$ t \leq x_2 \leq k$$

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying with the constraints is basically that you have two cases, and in both cases you need $x_2$ to be in between $x_3$ and $x_1$.

One way to linearize this is to say that we want to minimize $$\epsilon\left|\frac{x_3+x_1}{2} - x_2\right|$$ i.e. to push $x_2$ to be close towards the (arithmetic) mean value of $x_1$ and $x_3$. Maybe one can derive how large $\epsilon$ are suitable. Too large and $x_2$ would be forced to be exactly the mean value.